# How do I fix a door frame that my dog chewed?

Tags: doors

My dog chewed the bottom part of the doorframe to my bedroom.  I live in a rented apartment, so this is not OK.

Is there any way to fix it and make it look somewhat presentable (doesn't have to be perfect)?

How do I find a matching frame?  How do I match the paint?

[image]

**Update**: Just wanted to thank everyone for their help!

@XOPJ: Thanks, that is useful to know.  Actually, I don't think she actually chewed it, but simply scratched at it when I left her in the room for a while (she's got separation anxiety).  So my description was not quite accurate to begin with!

Regarding replacing the trim, I think that's just too much work for someone like me who doesn't know much about DIY projects.  I considered this initially before coming to this forum, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to remove the trim, and I'm afraid I'd knock a huge chunk out that I'm not supposed to if I tried to pry it off!

My filler experiment has been a half-success:  I had one big chunk which I managed to glue back in place, and I filled in the rest with wood filler and painted over it.  Since it's near the bottom of the door, you don't notice it unless you're looking for it.  However, I think I'll try to touch it up at some point in the future.

Comment: Once you get it fixed put Tabasco sauce on the bottom of the doors. That worked for us.

Comment: lol https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/repairing-eroded-plywood-window-casing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is some general advice.

Since larger chunks of wood are missing, use [**wood filler**](http://www.elmers.com/product/detail/E887?filterPath=wood-filler) to fill it in (found at any home improvement store).  Use a putty knife to match the shape of the trim as closely as possible.  After the filler cures, use sand paper to round it out.

You will also need to paint over the filler.  Get a chip of the wood trim and take it with you to the home improvement store and get them to color-match the paint (you may also be able to pull a piece of the trim off the wall).

The other option would be to find similar trim at the store and replace the damaged piece.  Some fancy trims can be tough to match, but what you have looks pretty basic.

For what it's worth, in the last place we rented, our rabbit used to gnaw on the door trim in our bedroom.  We eventually trained the rabbit not to do that, but it took a while, and the damage got pretty bad.  We repaired the trim using the above methods.  We got our full security deposit back.

Comment: Wood filler may be poisonous, make sure you check the package before using it.  If the dog chews the frame again and gets a belly full of poison, it could be a very bad and potentially expensive vet visit.

Comment: If the dog is going to keep doing this seriously consider just replacing the trim around the entire door to match something you can easily find that looks similar. Wood filler or any other shapable putty you can use to remodel the damage will poison your dog if he continues to eat it.

Answer (score 23):

You can simply replace the molding. This profile is an inexpensive ranch casing, available from your local home center. You should be able to match it virtually exactly. It will be nailed to the wall. Buy a new piece to fit. You will need to miter the top end to fit with a miter saw, but you can buy an inexpensive miter box to do that task accurately.

Once you have cut the new piece to fit, take the old one off and bring it into any good paint store. They can match the paint exactly. A quart of paint will be enough to repaint the molding with lots to spare for touch ups.

Install the molding using finish nails, set into place using a nail set. Then fill the heads with putty and paint.

Comment: You may be able to find the molding pre-painted, if it's just plain white. Caulk can fill in the nail holes without being too noticeable.

Comment: If you can't find molding that matches exactly, you could always replace the molding all the way around the door.

Comment: +1 for replacing the trim.  Trying to repair that much damage is a lost cause.  The door frame itself may be fixable though if the trim is replaced.

Answer (score 4):

It does look like pretty standard moulding, but if you can't match it exactly (the older the house the more likely this will be) and you want to, you may be able to find matching moulding inside a closet. Replace it with the closet moulding, and then replace the closet moulding with anything close - no one will ever notice or care.

Answer (score 1):

Its really a quite simple repair as long as you have the right tools and some good instructions.The tools that you would need are a Sheetrock knife to separate the molding from the wall without damaging the existing paint or drywall. A hammer and a flat screw driver to pry the molding off the wall. A hand saw to cut the a 45 degree angle on the new molding. A few finished nails to attach the new molding. A nail set to conceal the nails and some caulking. And a paint brush to paint the molding. I have included a few links to some photos of a similar project as well as a video that I found on repairing pet damage.

I am affiliated with this website as I am the owner but the video below is just a good relevant video that I found on youtube and I have no affiliations with it. I just thought it may be helpful to someone.

Photos  http://bobbyshandymanservice.com/handyman/

Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaJ_um27bJY