# How can I repair a door that a dog chewed on?

Tags: repair, doors, damage

My dog is an escape artist and managed to get out of her crate today. She then tried to chew her way through my bedroom door to escape confinement. Though unsuccessful, she did damage a significant part of the door. I live in a rented apartment and I would like to know if there is a way to fix this short of replacing the door. If not, is there a way to replace the door that would match this door (and the others in the apartment)? I would like to get my security deposit back if possible!

I will try to post a picture but it's proving challenging from my phone at the moment.

Comment: You'll only be able to add a link to a picture until you gain some reputation (see the [faq](http://diy.stackexchange.com/faq)).  If you can't provide a photo at least describe the door: hollow core vs. solid; single panel vs. 4-panel or 6-panel or...; painted vs. natural wood; and so on.

Comment: See also: [How do I fix a door frame that my dog chewed?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/4043/22)

Comment: If it's a cheap hollow-core door, probably easiest to buy a new one ($50 or so).

Comment: @DA01: I agree that it may be cheaper to replace, but the knowledge of how to install it, not to mention caulk and paint, makes it a non-trivial job. When you factor in tools, the landlord may be able to do it cheaper. Best to ask first.

Answer (score 1):

If its hollow then there no way to fix it unless its just on the surface. If its painted than you can just apply some wood filler and sand smooth and repaint the area. It will look as good as new.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen auto fiberglass repair (the type used for auto body) used to repair rotten parts of wood window sills.  If the marks made by the door are very deep but don't make a hole thru the surface of the door, you could try that.  To keep him from chewing wood surfaces in the future your dog needs more mental stimulation and daily long walks-preferably before you leave for an extended time. Chew toys also help. Many dogs stop needing to chew things after they are 1 to 2 years old. Also, keeping all doors closed will help as well as daily training sessions.